# Error when knitting R Sweave (.Rnw) file to .TeX: "page" is not a graphical parameter

Tags: r, latex, knitr, tex

I am trying to knit R Sweave files to .tex.  When I knit the following document, the file knits fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}
```

Here's the knit command:

```
knit(input="C:/Users/Isaac/Desktop/Test.Rnw", output="C:/Users/Isaac/Desktop/Test.tex")
```

When I knit the following document, however, I receive an error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Test

<<sample, echo=FALSE>>=
N <- 65
@

\end{document}
```

Here's the error:

```
Warning in par("page") : "page" is not a graphical parameter
Quitting from lines 7-8 (C:/Users/Isaac/Desktop/Test.Rnw) 
Error in !par("page") : invalid argument type
```

This seemed to be working fine before I upgraded to knitr 1.50.  Any ideas?  I would like to include R chunks in the sweave file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought CRAN would build binaries for each version of R separately, but it turns out that this is not the case. It builds the same Windows binary for all 3.0.x versions. The recommended solution for your problem is to upgrade to R 3.0.2; otherwise you have to install the `evaluate` package from source:

```
install.packages('evaluate', type = 'source')
```

The underlying problem is the `evaluate` package checks if `page` is in `par()` in the source code. Because CRAN uses R 3.0.2, this condition is true, whereas it is not the case in your version of R.

Comment: Helpful response and explanation!

Comment: Just FYI, I have fixed this problem in evaluate 0.5.1, which should appear on CRAN shortly.